# How to match the etherscan.io bytecode using the solc compiler?

Tags: etherscan, solc

Trying to do some simple sanity checks between the verified contracts on etherscan.io and the bytecode available on the blockchain for those contracts.

I picked a random contract to test:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x261c9420c9a67b806afef8b7597f7f5171434c4d#code

The source code shown is:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

library SafeMath {
  function mul(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    if (a == 0) {
      return 0;
    }
    uint256 c = a * b;
    assert(c / a == b);
    return c;
  }

  function div(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a / b;
    return c;
  }

  function sub(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    assert(b <= a);
    return a - b;
  }

  function add(uint256 a, uint256 b) internal pure returns (uint256) {
    uint256 c = a + b;
    assert(c >= a);
    return c;
  }
}

contract ERC20Basic {
  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256);
  function balanceOf(address who) public view returns (uint256);
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
}

contract BasicToken is ERC20Basic {
  using SafeMath for uint256;

  mapping(address => uint256) balances;

  uint256 totalSupply_;

  function totalSupply() public view returns (uint256) {
    return totalSupply_;
  }

  function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);

    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
  }

}

contract ERC20 is ERC20Basic {
  function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view returns (uint256);
  function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  function approve(address spender, uint256 value) public returns (bool);
  event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);
}

contract StandardToken is ERC20, BasicToken {

  mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) internal allowed;

  function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    require(_to != address(0));
    require(_value <= balances[_from]);
    require(_value <= allowed[_from][msg.sender]);

    balances[_from] = balances[_from].sub(_value);
    balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
    allowed[_from][msg.sender] = allowed[_from][msg.sender].sub(_value);
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
  }

  function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) public view returns (uint256) {
    return allowed[_owner][_spender];
  }

  function increaseApproval(address _spender, uint _addedValue) public returns (bool) {
    allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = allowed[msg.sender][_spender].add(_addedValue);
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

  function decreaseApproval(address _spender, uint _subtractedValue) public returns (bool) {
    uint oldValue = allowed[msg.sender][_spender];
    if (_subtractedValue > oldValue) {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = 0;
    } else {
      allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = oldValue.sub(_subtractedValue);
    }
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, allowed[msg.sender][_spender]);
    return true;
  }

}

contract WBC_TOKEN is StandardToken {
  string public name    = "WBC TOKEN";
  string public symbol  = "WBC";
  uint8 public decimals = 18;
  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 200000000;
  event Burn(address indexed _from, uint256 _tokenDestroyed, uint256 _timestamp);

  function WBC_TOKEN() public {
    totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
    balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply_;
  }

  function burn(uint256 _burntAmount) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _burntAmount && _burntAmount > 0);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_burntAmount);
    totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.sub(_burntAmount);
    emit Transfer(address(this), 0x0, _burntAmount);
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _burntAmount, block.timestamp);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Compiler details from Etherscan are as follows:

> Compiler Text:    v0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c
>
> Optimization Enabled:     No
>
> Runs (Optimiser):     200

I put this source into a .sol file, and ran the following:

```
C:\Temp\solc>solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.21+commit.dfe3193c.Windows.msvc

C:\Temp\solc>solc --bin wbc_token.sol --optimize-runs 200
```

The output from this command is:

```
======= wbc_token.sol:WBC_TOKEN =======
Binary:
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
```

This does not match the expected output from etherscan.io of:

```
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
```

Another thread recommended I remove the carrot from the `pragma solidity` version, but that did not resolve the mismatch.

Are there some other configurations I am missing?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of magic required to actually verify the contract bytecode: see [1](https://github.com/ConsenSys/bytecode-verifier/blob/master/src/verifier.js) and [2](https://github.com/ConsenSys/bytecode-verifier/blob/master/BYTECODE_EXPLAINED.md)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two binaries are identical expect for the metadata part, which consists of the 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters) preceding the last 2 bytes (4 hexadecimal characters).

This is possibly related to how the deployed code was compiled.

For example, when compiling with Truffle, the path of the source file impacts the metadata.

Generally speaking, you have nothing to worry about.

---

UPDATE:

As of solc 0.5.x, those last 2 bytes have changed to 11 bytes (22 hexadecimal characters).

Comment: Generally this answer is right. According to [this](https://github.com/ConsenSys/bytecode-verifier/blob/master/src/verifier.js#L59) we should be looking for `a165627a7a72305820` which represents the ending point of the actual contract bytecode. With that information, the bytecode matches.

Comment: This ending pattern is sort of documented [here](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/metadata.html#encoding-of-the-metadata-hash-in-the-bytecode) for those who want to get more details.

Comment: Note to future readers: the metadata is in fact the 32 bytes (64 hexadecimal characters) which appear right before the last 2 bytes (4 hexadecimal characters). Also, starting from solc 0.5.x, those 2 bytes have changed to 11 bytes (22 hexadecimal characters).